# for loop to assign column values on dynamic number of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple data frames called (df1, df2, df3, df4, etc.) with the following structure:

```
ID val1 val2
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  NA   3
4  NA   4
5  6    3
6  6    6
```

I want to assign the NA values in val1 with values in val2, I used the following to do so:

```
df1$val1[is.na(df$val1)] <- df1$val2[is.na(df1$val1)]
```

This works well!

**Problem:**

I don't want to write multiple such statements to handle this, because number of data frames is large say 10

I know how to dynamically create data frames but I can't do the same for this!

**Inspiration:**

```
for(i in 1:10){ 
  assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), subset(df2, count == i))}
```

**P.S:** Merging df's together is not allowed

Comment: @RonakShah: Made the change sorry, yes i meant assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list` and do the same operation.  If we need to change the values in the original objects, wrap it with `list2env`

```
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:10))
list2env(lapply(lst, function(x) {i1 <- is.na(x$val1)
                         x$val1[i1] <- x$val2[i1]
                         x }), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

This can be also done more efficiently with `data.table`

```
list2env(lapply(lst, function(x) setDT(x)[is.na(val1), val1:= val2]), 
                envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I tired both the methods, data.table method is definitely easier to understand thanks a lot

Comment: @akrun thank you for `list2env()` I needed this func at my work! great!